# Передача параметра-указателя в функцию всегда выполняется по значению

Tags: c, функции, указатели

```
typedef struct
{
    char c;
} s;
void fonction(s * ps)
{
    ps = (s *)malloc(sizeof(s));
 }
```

Код упрощён. Правильно ли я понимаю, что так делать не правильно? Как тогда поменять переданную структуру в функции? В функцию была передана копия адреса структуры? Malloc вернёт указатель, присвоит его локальной переменной, но почему структура не поменяется, не понимаю, ведь у локальной переменной тот же адрес, или нет? Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит, и как правильно.

**Обновление**

```
void function (s ** pps)
{
   s new[10];
   initialize_array(new);
   *pps = (s *)realloc(pps, 10 * sizeof(s));
}
int main(void)
{
   s * ps;
   initialize_array1(ps);
   function(&ps);
   free(ps);
}
```

Comment: что должна была делать ваша функция? Если поменять структуру, то так : `ps -> c = 'A';`

Comment: В полной версии я полностью перезаписываю структуру временной структурой, созданной в функции, а вне функции освобождаю память.

Comment: проще понять, если вы покажите пример использовании вашей `fonction` и точную задачу, что вы не смогли сделать.

Comment: Добавил пример кода в стартовое сообщение. Правильно ли я там работаю с памятью? В исходном варианте у меня double free.

Comment: пока вижу три ошибки : надо указатель как нибудь установить `s * ps    = NULL    ;` , функция `initialize_array1(ps);` непонятно что делает при отсутствии объекта вообще и `realloc(    * pps    , 10 * sizeof(s))` нужно с добавлением звёздочки. *тяжело поставлен вопрос..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаёте в функцию *значение* указателя, которое присваивается переменной-аргументу функции при её вызове. Так что аргумент `ps` - это *копия* того указателя, что вы передаёте. По сути вы меняете значение *копии*, а оригинал остаётся неизменным. А ещё это временный объект, который уничтожается при возврате из функци, и у вас происходит утечка памяти.

Если требуется поменять исходный указатель, то в Си это можно сделать двумя способами.

1. Передать *указатель на указатель*, и присвоить значение исходному указателю через указатель на него:

   `void fonction(s **pps) { *pps = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s)); }`

Вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
s* ps;
fonction(&ps);
```

2. Сделать так, чтобы функция *возвращала* новый указатель, который можно присвоить исходному:

   `s* fonction() { return (s*)malloc(sizeof(s)); }`

Тогда вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
s* ps = fonction();
```

И кстати, не fonction, а function)

Comment: Не уверен, что второй вариант компилируется без предупреждений. В первом варианте мы передаём в функцию адрес указателя, а *pps - это имя указателя или его значение?

Comment: @Грузчик `pps` - это аргумент функции, который имеет тип `s**`, т.е. указатель на указатель на структуру `s`. В вызывающем коде `ps` - это указатель на структуру `s`, указатель на него (`&ps`) вы передаёте в функцию в качестве аргумента. В коде функции `*pps` - это разыменование указателя на указатель. Т.е., через это выражение вы меняете исходный указатель `ps`, которому присваиваете адрес, возвращённый функцией `malloc()`. Какие сомнения насчёт второго варианта? Откомпилируете - и узнаете, будут предупреждения (о чём?), или нет...

Comment: Можно ли разыменование указателя на указатель понимать как *(**pps)?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что любой указатель - это адрес: что &ps, что **pps?

Comment: @Грузчик `&` - это операция взятия адреса. `*` (в выражениях) - это операция обращения по адресу (разыменование). Они обратны друг другу. И не следует путать **объявление** указателя с его **разыменованием**. Например, `s **pps` - это **объявление** переменной типа `s**` (указатель на указатель на тип `s`), а в выражении `**pps = my_s` - это **двойное разыменование ** (объекту типа `s`, на который ссылается указатель, на который в свою очередь ссылается указатель `pps`, присваивается значение переменой `my_s`). Не запутались ещё?)))

Comment: А более двух * может быть для чего-то?

Comment: @Грузчик ...А в выражении `*pps = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s))` указателю, на который ссылается указатель `pps` присваивается указатель на динамически созданный блок памяти, имеющий тип `s`. Замечу, что ещё не проинициализированный (поля только что созданной структуры ещё содержат мусор).

Comment: @Грузчик *"А более двух `*` может быть для чего-то?"*. Может, синтаксис Си такое не запрещает. Но на практике, использование даже двойных разыменований считается плохим стилем программирования, т.к. ухудшает читабельность кода. А если вдруг возникнет потребность в цепочках из трёх и более указателей, то это будет означать только одно - данный код никуда не годится и его нужно подвергнуть редизайну.

Comment: Почему вариант с ** pps работает?